# How to force text being entered into a textbox into Uppercase?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, uppercase, textchanged

I want to make the text that a user is typing into a textbox become uppercase.  I know two ways to do this, which are:

```
Textbox1.Text = UCase(Textbox1.Text)
or
Textbox1.Text = Textbox1.Text.ToUpper
```

HOWEVER: both have the same problem (when embedded in a `Textbox1_TextChanged` event handler), which is that the cursor keeps being moved back to the start, so if you slowly type in, say abcdef, it comes out as FEDCBA.  Is there a way to move the cursor back to the end of the string after each time it works to make the text uppercase?

Answer (score 8):

go to textbox property, change `CharacterCasing` to `Upper`

[image]

Comment: This is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use the KeyPress event to detect lower case letters being entered, and convert them to uppercase as you go:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  If KeyAscii > 96 And KeyAscii < 123 Then
    'Typed letter from "a-z", map it to "A-Z"
    KeyAscii = KeyAscii - 32
  End If
End Sub
```

`Ucase()` is used only after the person is done entering the text.

If you are using VB.NET then you just need to set the `.CharacterCasing` property of the TextBox to `.Upper` - No code needed. But if you wanted to use code for some reason, use this:

```
TextBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
```

Comment: Thanks!  One followup - when I create an event "Keypress" for that textbox it automatically generates this:

Comment: Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress - can I just replace it with yours?

Comment: If that's what it's giving you, then you are not using VBA, you are using Visual Studio and VB.NET - they are not the same thing. I updated the answer to include how to do it in VB.NET

Comment: Thanks for the tip about CharacterCasing - that also works!  However, all the Keypress stuff is not a waste of time, because I also want to use it to analyze what is being typed.

Comment: I've changed the tags from VBA to VB.Net, because you're right.  This is obviously a basic confusion, but I am a total amateur trying to teach myself from scratch - I got the software for free from  my university.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just place the code `Textbox1.Text = Textbox1.Text.ToUpper` in the `Textbox1_LostFocus` event instead of the `Textbox1_TextChanged event`.  It's so simple and it works even if you paste text into the field. As soon as your cursor moves to another field, the event is triggered, causing the text to change case from lower to upper.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
Private Sub Textbox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.KeyPress
    e.KeyChar = UCase(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

... if you need to do some custom formatting or logic. Otherwise I'd also suggest using the default TextBox property `CharacterCasing` set to `Upper`.

**Please note** that this solution does not handle the situation when user is pasting text into the TextBox component and you have to programmatically take care of that situation too if needed, but the TextBox property `CharacterCasing` does it for you even if user is pasting text into the component.

Answer (score -1):

Your version didn't quite work for me in Visual Basic 2019, but it formed the basis of this, which does (where "txtPrem1" is the TextBox):

```
Private Sub txtPrem1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPrem1.KeyPress
        Dim KeyAscii = AscW(e.KeyChar)
        If KeyAscii > 96 And KeyAscii < 123 Then
            'Typed letter from "a-z", map it to "A-Z"
            KeyAscii = KeyAscii - 32
        End If
        e.KeyChar = ChrW(KeyAscii)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Argh - how to I format it to get it to look right? (Sorry - total newbie)

Comment: There is no need to do all of that in VB.NET - Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
Private Sub MyText_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                              Handles MyText.TextChanged
    Dim oText As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    oText.Text = oText.Text.ToUpper
    oText.SelectionStart = oText.Text.Length
    oText.SelectionLength = 0
End Sub
```